# Position a View for drawing via renderInContext:

Tags: ios, core-graphics, calayer, cgcontext

I want to draw a `UIView` in my current `CGGraphicsContext`. I draw the `UIView` via `renderInContext:`, but it's not positioned correctly (always in the top left corner).

I have all values of the `UIView` available for drawing the `UIView`.

```
CGRect frame;
CGRect bound;
CGPoint center;
CGAffineTransform transform;
```

I currently set the position and rotation of the layer like this:

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y);
CGContextRotateCTM(context, (CGFloat) atan2(transform.b, transform.a));
```

But the position is, due to the rotation, not correct and differs from the original position. 
How can I restore the original position? The coordinate system hasn't changed in between, it's just an issue to translate the `center.x` and `center.y` values into something appropriate for `CGContextTranslateCTM`.

**Edit:** 
The saved values are correct, saving the correct `bounds`, `center` and `transform` is not the origin of my issue, the origin of my issue, is setting theses values to the drawable `CGLayer` via `CGContextTranslateCTM`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The geometry of the graphics context can be adjusted to the `UIView`s geometry with this snippet:

```
// Center the context around the view's anchor point
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [view center].x, [view center].y);
// Apply the view's transform about the anchor point
CGContextConcatCTM(context, [view transform]);
// Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                      -[view bounds].size.width * [[view layer] anchorPoint].x,
                      -[view bounds].size.height * [[view layer] anchorPoint].y);
```

Comment: This is very nice explained, thanks for the comments :-). Together with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36440774/issue-capturing-selected-views-as-they-appear-on-screen-with-renderincontext-in is the solution I was searching for :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new layer sized to match CGContext's size, add your view.layer as a sublayer to the newly created layer, and then position your view.layer accordingly.

```objectivec
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                             1000.f,
                                             1000.f,
                                             16,
                                             20480,
                                             colorSpace,
                                             4353);

CALayer *copiedLayer = [view.layer copy];
CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer new];

parentLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.f,
                                0.f,
                                CGBitmapContextGetWidth(context),
                                CGBitmapContextGetHeight(context));

copiedLayer.frame = view.frame;

[parentLayer addSublayer:copiedLayer];
[parentLayer renderInContext:context];
```