# Issue capturing selected views as they appear on screen with renderInContext in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uigraphicscontext

I have three views on my storyboard, `viewA`, `viewB`, `viewC`.

I’m trying to screen capture **only** two views as they appear on screen in their current place, **`viewB`** and **`viewC`**.

The trouble is, when I render them, the resulting image captured shows `viewB` and `viewC` in incorrect locations, the position of the views change moving top left (0, 0), see image.

How can I correct the code below so that I can capture the views `viewB` and `viewC` exactly as they are positioned on the view using the `renderInContext` implementation below?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, false, 0)
self.viewB.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
self.viewC.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs for `renderInContext:`:

> Renders in the coordinate space of the layer.

Each view's layer has an origin of 0,0 so they each appear in the upper-left corner.

To fix this you need to translate the graphics context by the view's origin before calling `renderInContext:`.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, false, 0)
let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, self.viewB.frame.origin.x, self.viewB.frame.origin.y)
self.viewB.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)

CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, self.viewC.frame.origin.x, self.viewC.frame.origin.y)
self.viewC.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)

let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @rmaddy . How do I "translate the graphics context" specifically?

Comment: See my update. I believe that is correct. It's not tested.

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy . I've tested that and it works. I had to change the `-self.viewC` to `self.viewC` removing the `-` for it to work. I’ve since added a new view and am having trouble capturing that for some reason, it never shows, I suspect it might be related to auto constraints but not sure why which I’m investigating.

Comment: This answer + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110601/position-a-view-for-drawing-via-renderincontext is exactly what is needed. Love SO :-)